# Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 eclipse

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

```
**Error :** Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

This error is getting when i am running the task which is build.gradle file as follows,

```
 plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'eclipse'
}

// remove the Javadoc verification
tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
    options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
}

// Build version
version = '1.2.6-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

artifactory {
    publish {
         repository.repoKey = 'ent-public-local-builds'
    }
}

eclipse.classpath {
    containers = containers.collect {
        it.replace 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER',
            'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/DeveloperJavaJDK'
    }
}

//Core Spring version numbers
def springVersion = '5.1.9.RELEASE'
def springBatchVersion = '4.1.2.RELEASE'

//Junit version
def junitVersion = '5.5.1'

//updated to use Transitive Dependencies
dependencies {
    // include Spring JARs and dependencies
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-oxm:' + springVersion
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:' + springVersion
}

reporting.baseDir = "my-reports"
testResultsDirName = "$buildDir/my-test-results"

application {
    mainClassName = 'com.automation.MyClass'
}
task runWithJavaExec(type: JavaExec) {
   // group = 'Execution'
   // description = "Run the main class with JavaExecTask"
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'com.automation.MyClass'
}
runWithJavaExec.onlyIf { project.hasProperty('Execution')}
```

I ran this task by using below command,

```
gradle runWithJavaExec
```

Finally,I want to know how to run java class through gradle command ?Is there any possibility other than creation of a task?
If yes please share accordingly.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: There is likely more information about the problem in the output above the error you posted. If not, try running Gradle with `-s` (with stack traces) or maybe even `-is` (set log to INFO level and with stack traces).

Comment: When i ran using --stacktrace , now i am getting this  Task :runWithJavaExec SKIPPED
Skipping task ':runWithJavaExec' as task onlyIf is false.
:runWithJavaExec (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 15,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs. This task execution has been skipped .

Comment: Can anyone help me in how to run a task without skipping ?

Comment: @BjørnVester please share your thought on this issue

Comment: The line `runWithJavaExec.onlyIf { project.hasProperty('Execution')}` means it should only run when you provide a property called Execution. Not sure why you have that in there, but maybe try `gradle -is -PExecution runWithJavaExec` and post the output leading up to and including the failure. As to why your application fails, that can really be anything. Maybe Spring can't find some required beans to autowire, maybe the runtime classpath is incomplete or similar.

Answer (score 22):

If you are using the intellij just invalidate the caches and restart

Comment: need specific steps to do this

Comment: This fixed my issue. Steps are pretty basic ... File -> invalidate cache.. -> invalidate and restart

I was able to invalidate and restart the cache through this link https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html

Comment: Helped thanks, normally you don't expect this from Intellij. Please fix this kind of bugs jetbrains team...

Comment: This Fixed my issue, just tap double shift on intelliJ and just type cache , you will get option of invalidateCache in list, select and choose option and done, thanks

Answer (score 7):

This happen usually when you define a property file or some file in the code, But when application running it try to get the file but it cannot locate file in the project. You should move the files to resource folder.

Answer (score 3):

Change the port number on which you're running your springboot application. It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

**Error :** Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1...

This error is showing because some other service is running on the same port as the one you are running on your application. For example your application maybe trying to run on port 8080 but some other application is also running on port 8080. To solve this you can

1. stop all services running on the port for example stop services that are running on port 8080 or
2. you can just change the application port in the applications.properties to a new port for example change the port your application is running on from 8080 to 8081

Comment: This answer is similar to another one.  But you could enhance it by showing how to find the services that are using that port.

Comment: Would be great if you explain how to do 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have DB plugins in your project but you did not specify DB details in application.property file.

Answer (score 0):

If using Ktor, check that the Netty engine has the correct class in the build.gradle:

```
application {
    mainClass = 'com.octagon_technologies.songa.server.ApplicationKt'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - in your terminal run: java --version
[terminal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnF35.png)

2 - change in build.gradle the param `sourceCompatibility` for your actual java version.
[gradle image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgBeo.png)

Answer (score 0):

i found one way to solucionate this error.

I changed the port where my application run (default is 8080)

In the resources foulder there is a file called application.properties.

you need this line of code:
server.port = 8888

I guess this way can helps you...

(Sorry for my english, i'm learning...)

Comment: I hate when people say "sorry for my English"... especially after speaking perfect English.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar problem because there is no corresponding `.class` file in the build directory

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31988695)

Answer (score 0):

For me I am using swagger2 with spring boot 2, Java 8, Gradle 2. I used below property in the application.properties. this works for me

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher
```