# Process 'command 'C:/Users/RAKITAN/.jdks/jdk-18.0.2.1/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 for LIBGDX

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx

I know there is already a question to this, but I'm a beginner and all the links I've read didn't really help me so this is kind of my last resort of the night

so I'm trying to create a game on libgdx, at the start when I run the default badlogic game it seems normal and runs just fine.

but when I add my own codes (I know maybe there's an mistake on my code), but instead of displaying my errors it says this:
Execution failed for task ':desktop:DesktopLauncher.main()'.

> Process 'command 'C:/Users/RAKITAN/.jdks/jdk-18.0.2.1/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I've tried:

- I checked and echoing the java version on cmd and it seems right (jdk 18):
  [cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0WsU.png)
- I also already tried the 'invalidate cache and restart' method as the top comment said on [Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60651244/process-command-c-program-files-java-jdk-bin-java-exe-finished-with-non-zer)
- Create an env VAR JAVA_HOME and configure the enviroment variables
- Tried re-installing IntelliJ

What is actually the problem here? Do I have to delete and re-download the JDKs?
If I need to post something related to the question feel free to let me know. Thanks

Comment: Yes, there is a question open on this. Please post a link to it. Also, [please never post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.
You should have posted the output of `echo %JAVA_HOME%` *as code-formatted text*. That is showing you that your Java home is in quite a different place from the Java that's being used to run. You need to *pre*pend `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;` to `PATH`